# How do I use web deploy to deploy sub site in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, web-deployment, azure-web-roles

I have a web role with multiple sites accessible using different port numbers.
e.g. (main site) http://site.cloudapp.net , (sub sites ) http://site.cloudapp.net:8080, http://site.cloudapp.net:8081

I can use web deploy to deploy the main site . How can I use web deploy to deploy the sub sites?

Answer (score 7):

You can deploy to a sub-application by prefixing it with the parent site name. For example `mysite/myapplication`. [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx) has more details if you need them.

However, I'd be more concerned since you said you are doing this with an Azure web role which are deployed on virtual machines with ephemeral disks (non-persistent if the hardware fails or needs to be redeployed). If Azure re-deploys your web role to another VM your "web deployed" changes will be lost and the contents of your cspkg will be redeployed. If you really want to use web deploy your should consider using Azure Web Sites or Azure Virtual Machines, otherwise to ensure your changes are not lost you'll need to republish the full cspkg file and allow Azure to deploy the changes to all your instances.